# Neural Networks - Do all neurons in hidden layer activate?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

Noob question.

Okay I am beginning with MLPs and machine learning.

Suppose that I have 2 hidden layers in an ANN that uses the sigmoid function.

So does that mean that after calculating the weighted sum of inputs from the input layer **all neurons in the hidden layer will only output a value between 0 and 1 in each of the neurons** ?

**Or will they output a weighted sum in the hidden layers and ONLY when it goes to the output neurons will the activation function be used.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very unclear what you want, but I'll try.

Yes, the output of each sigmoidal neuron is strictly between 0 and 1 due to the definition of sigmoidal function. These outputs become input vector in the second layer, so yeah, in a sense they 'output a weighted sum in the hidden' layer. Is this what ou wanted?

Comment: Yes. This what I wanted. Thanks. So let me just get it straight. After calculating the weighted sum a neuron passes that sum into a sigmoid(or any activation function) and calculates a value which becomes a input for the next layer. That means all neurons pass the weighted sum through an activation function, I mean there is no neuron that passes just the weighted sum to the next layer without the activation function, RIGHT ???

Comment: You can use the linear function, i.e. $f(x) = x$, it is even continuous, but what's the point?

Comment: Exactly, so the activation is done at every hidden layer. You see I am not confused about the parameters. I am confused about the fact that after calculating the parameters is the final result passed through an activation function in the hidden layer(NOT the OUTPUT LAYER)

Comment: 'after calculating the parameters'-?? I'm sorry, it's very unclear what you want. 'calculating the parameters', i.e. weights and hidden unit expressions are very different things

Comment: Sorry after multiplying the inputs with the weights.

Comment: yes, it is 'passed through an activation function in the hidden layer', if that was your question